# Using L'Hopitals rule.

Tags: calculus, limits

I've attempted to solve this problem multiple times and I keep getting 0/infinity, and then plugging it back into e^0 yielding 1 as my answer, but my pal told me in passing that I was incorrect and I've been trying to figure out where I've gone wrong for about 90 minutes now to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated. Accompanying this are the question and my work thus far. 
Edit: The problem is lim x--->infinity of (1+1/x)^x. I pulled e outside of the limit after using e^bln(a), leaving e[lim x-->infinity of xln(1+5/x)]. Dropped x down, and differentiated the top and bottom getting 0/infinity. 
[My Work on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPxSM.jpg)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: My apologies. Should I re-ask with the math I've done typed out?

Comment: @Dknowlez In a word: yes.

Comment: You can [edit] your existent question. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to solve this:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+ \frac{5}{x}\right)^{x}$$

Up until this point you have solved correctly:

$$=e^{\lim_{x\to\infty} x \times \log(1+\frac{5}{x})}$$

For sanity, replace $x$ with $1/t$, which takes our problem to:

$$e^{\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t} \times \log(1+5t)}$$

Now apply L'Hospital rule.

In your attempt, I checked, you didn't differentiate the denominator in the exponent.

Just so you are reminded of the L'Hospital rule correctly, it states that:

If $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, then

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I differentiated the denominator and got 30/6 or 5. Now, I admittedly didn't use your method, but I'm curious as to how it would lend itself to my cause. How can you change the limit?

Comment: Change the limit, I didn't quite understand you?

Answer (score 0):

$lim_{x \to \infty} x \log (1+5/x)=lim_{x \to \infty} x (\log (5+x)-\log(x))$. This is $lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\log (5+x)-\log(x)} {1/x}$. By L'Hopital's Rule this becomes $lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {1/(5+x)-1/x} {-1/x^{2}}$. Some simple algebraic manipulation now gives the limit as $5$ so the original limit is $e^{5}$.